# resolving linking dependencies mac os x

Tags: macos, software-distribution, building

I compiled some source code to build and app, everything compiles fine but now I am getting linking/ dependency errors so the app crashes on load.

Here is an the error

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: libstreamanalyzer.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libkio.5.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

using otool -L on this file in question i get

```
/opt/krita/lib/libkio.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.14.3)
/opt/krita/lib/libkdeui.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.14.3)
/usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/QtNetwork (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.6)
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/lib/QtXml.framework/Versions/4/QtXml (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.6)
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/lib/QtSvg.framework/Versions/4/QtSvg (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.6)
libstreamanalyzer.0.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.7.8)
libstreams.0.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.7.8)
/opt/krita/lib/libsolid.4.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.14.3)
/opt/krita/lib/libkdecore.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.14.3)
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/lib/QtDBus.framework/Versions/4/QtDBus (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.6)
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.6)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 157.0.0)
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.6)
/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

anyone have any tips on solving this issue?

[EDIT]
using find on my system it shows

```
/opt/krita/lib/cmake/LibStreamAnalyzer/LibStreamAnalyzerConfig.cmake
/opt/krita/lib/pkgconfig/libstreamanalyzer.pc
/opt/krita/lib/libstreamanalyzer.0.7.8.dylib
/opt/krita/lib/libstreamanalyzer.0.dylib
/opt/krita/lib/libstreamanalyzer.dylib
```

doing
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/krita/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
like vsoftco suggested and the app still crashes with the exact same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS cannot find the dynamic library. Apple's OS X is a bit different from linux, and even if you link the library successfully, you may still get in trouble when running the program.

The solution is to set the environment variable

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

to the path where your library `libstreamanalyzer` is located. From the OS X console, type

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/library:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

then try running the program.

If you run the program from an IDE like XCode or Eclipse, there is an option of specifying environment variables.

Comment: I tried that but it still crashes, see my latest edit.

Comment: are you running the program from the terminal line? if yes, make sure you run the program from the same terminal session (i.e., don't close the terminal or open a new tab, as the export statement is not persistent, unless you put it in your .profile)

Comment: Yes I am trying it directly in the same terminal after exporting the path.

Comment: @steffan not sure then what is going on, usually this should have done it. I assume you use bash. Is the path set when you type `echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Also, try putting the path inside double quotes like  `"path/to/lib"` and just use `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/krita/lib"` Hope it works.